# Logging the particular level (FATAL) in a different file with the name as current date using log4j

Tags: java, file, logging, log4j, log4j2

I want to log only FATAL level in a different logfile with the current date as its name. i have tried like below

```
# Console appender configuration
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p: %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.b=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.b.LevelToMatch=FATAL    
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.b.AcceptOnMatch=false

#File appender configuration
log4j.appender.fileout = org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.fileout.File = F:/Logs/log1.log
log4j.appender.fileout.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileout.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.fileout.Threshold=FATAL
log4j.appender.fileout.Append=true
log4j.appender.fileout.filter.a=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter
log4j.appender.fileout.filter.a.LevelToMatch=FATAL    
log4j.appender.fileout.filter.a.AcceptOnMatch=true
```

with this i am able to print into different file but unable to change the name dynamically as current date.. please suggest a solution

I am using log4j 1.2.13

Comment: http://veerasundar.com/blog/2011/05/log4j-tutorial-writing-different-log-levels-in-different-log-files/

Comment: isn't there any another way other than this..?? can we do it by using wither fileAppender or DailyRollingFileAppender???

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "change the name dynamically"? I am also interested in this feature and didn't know about "LevelToMatch". Will try it...

Comment: with the above code FATAL logs are printing in F:/Logs/log1.log file but i want those logs to be printed in the file like this F:/Logs/log1-11-7-14.log (should append the current date to the file name)

Comment: @mvidelgauz I think the answer below will also be useful to you have a look at it

Comment: @phanisekhar Thank you! Looks like what I am also looking for. I'll check if it works also for log4cxx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following configuration now i can able to print only the FATAL logs into the different log file with current date as its name

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, rollingAppender
# Console appender configuration
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p: %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.b=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.b.LevelToMatch=FATAL    
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.b.AcceptOnMatch=false

#File appender configuration
log4j.appender.rollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingAppender.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.rollingAppender.rollingPolicy.fileNamePattern=F:/temp/app%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
log4j.appender.rollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= %d %c %M - %m%n
log4j.appender.rollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingAppender.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.rollingAppender.Threshold=FATAL
log4j.appender.rollingAppender.Append=true
log4j.appender.rollingAppender.filter.a=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter
log4j.appender.rollingAppender.filter.a.LevelToMatch=FATAL    
log4j.appender.rollingAppender.filter.a.AcceptOnMatch=true
```

we have to add [(apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar)](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=log4j/apache-log4j-extras/1.2.17/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar)